# Can't install packages

Tags: terminal, package-management, kali-linux

I'm trying to install the Banshee music-player, but everytime I type

```
apt-get install Banshee
```

I get this response.

```
root@kali:~# apt-get install Banshee
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package Banshee
```

After that I thought maybe some sources are missing, so typed them also in.

```
root@kali:~# deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali main non-free contrib
bash: deb: command not found
root@kali:~# deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free
bash: deb: command not found
root@kali:~# deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali main non-free contrib
bash: deb-src: command not found
root@kali:~# deb-src http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free
bash: deb-src: command not found
```

Then I found some post with the same problem, saying type `sudo` in, but since I'm logged in as root this must not be a problem for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Banshee (the animal) is not the same thing as `banshee` (the package name). These package names are case sensitive, and Debian packages have not been allowed to use upper case letters in their names since over fifteen years.

Also, the lines beginning with `deb` are *not* commands; they are URIs that should be entered into the apt configuration file for that purpose, `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Finally, note that you can *search* for packages with `apt-cache search <key word>`. This will search substrings of package names as well as descriptions. If there is no `banshee` package name (I haven't checked), then `apt-cache search banshee` should help.